# How to create a pattern that matches Group A except host "test-host" and Group B?

Tags: ansible

I have 2 groups of servers A and B, one of servers that I need to exclude is in group A

I tried following pattern:

```
GroupA:!test-host,GroupB
```

Which results in 'no hosts matched'

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inventory

```sh
shell> cat hosts
[groupA]
test1
test2
test-host

[groupB]
test3
test4
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: groupB:groupA:!test-host
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

give

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

ok: [test3] => {
    "ansible_play_hosts_all": [
        "test3",
        "test4",
        "test1",
        "test2"
    ]
}
```

---

With *`- hosts: all`* in the playbook, the command gives the same result

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts -l 'groupB:groupA:!test-host' pb.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Use dynamic grouping (`group_by` module) to create a new group
2. pre-calculate variable with expected hostlist to run:

group_vars/all.yaml:

```
mygroup: '{{ groups.foo|difference(groups.bar) }}'
```

play:

```
hosts: '{{ mygroup }}'
```

3. Alternatively, you can terminate play for host if it's in the specific group.

   ```
   - name: Stop doing this for bar
     meta: end_host
     when: "'bar' in group_names"
   ```

Comment: is there any way to create some pattern for this that I could use with --limit?

Comment: Yes. `--limit 'foo:!bar'`.